# Convert Image to Uint8List Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, image, integer

**How to convert variable Image type to Uint8List?**

The variable get its value from shared preferences when App start like this:

```
String? img = prefs.getString('image');
Image imageOfBillHead = Image.memory(base64Decode(img));
```

I want to convert `imageOfBillHead` to `List<int>`?

**Edit:**

I can do this to convert the Image to Unit8List:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? _imgString = prefs.getString('image');

List<int> imageData =  Base64Decoder().convert(_imgString);
```

But I already get the image when app started and saved it in `imageOfBillHead`, so I don't want to get it again from shared preferences.

Is there way to convert `imageOfBillHead` to `Unit8List` or convert `imageOfBillHead` to `String` to use:

`List<int> imageData = Base64Decoder().convert(_imgString);`

Comment: `base64Decode(img)` is your `Uint8List`

Comment: No, you cannot turn an `Image` back to its original. As @pskink says, either keep hold of `img`,... or get it again from shared preferences (why don't you want to do that?)